# Is there a way in R to determine AIC from cv.glmnet?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, model-comparison

I am using the `glmnet` package in R, and not(!) the `caret` package for my binary ElasticNet regression. I have come to the point where I would like to compare models (e.g. lambda set to `lambda.1se` or `lambda.min`, and models where `k-fold` is set to 5 or 10). But, I have not yet achieved to compute the `AICc` or `BIC` for my models. How do I do that? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746925/12546311) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277205/290826) but it did not work for me, I only get an empty list.
Code:

```
set.seed(123)
foldid <- sample(rep(seq(10), length.out = nrow(x.train)))
list.of.fits.df <- list()
for (i in 0:10){
     fit.name <- paste0("alpha", i/10) 
     list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]] <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure = c("auc"), alpha = i/10, family = "binomial", nfolds = 10, foldid = foldid, parallel = TRUE)
 }
best.fit <- coef(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], s = list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]]$lambda.1se)
best.fit.min <- coef(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], s = list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]]$lambda.min)

#AICc & BIC
#???
```

How can I find the `AICc` and `BIC` for my best fit model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746925/10782538) answer slightly to obtain the desired result The reason it doesn't work "out of the box" is that the `cv.glmnet` function returns the result of several fits, but the individual results are stored in `x$glmnet.fit`, and we can use this to create a simple function for calculating `AICc` and `BIC`.

```
glmnet_cv_aicc <- function(fit, lambda = 'lambda.1se'){
  whlm <- which(fit$lambda == fit[[lambda]])
  with(fit$glmnet.fit,
       {
         tLL <- nulldev - nulldev * (1 - dev.ratio)[whlm]
         k <- df[whlm]
         n <- nobs
         return(list('AICc' = - tLL + 2 * k + 2 * k * (k + 1) / (n - k - 1),
                     'BIC' = log(n) * k - tLL))
       })
}
```

All we'll then have to do is provide the model and get our estimated `AICc`.

```
best.aicc <- glmnet_cv_aicc(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]])
best.aicc.min <- glmnet_cv_aicc(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], 'lambda.min')
```

For a reproducible example, one could use one of the many examples provided in `help(glmnet)`

```
n = 500
p = 30
nzc = trunc(p/10)
x = matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
beta3 = matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
beta3 = rbind(beta3, matrix(0, p - 10, 3))
f3 = x %*% beta3
p3 = exp(f3)
p3 = p3/apply(p3, 1, sum)
g3 = glmnet:::rmult(p3)
set.seed(10101)
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, g3, family = "multinomial")
print(glmnet_cv_aicc(cvfit))
# Output
#$AICc
#[1] -556.2404
#
#$BIC
#[1] -506.3058
print(glmnet_cv_aicc(cvfit, 'lambda.min'))
# Output
#$AICc
#[1] -601.0234
#
#$BIC
#[1] -506.4068
```

Comment: Wauw! Amazing, really plug and conduct in R with the `cv.glmnet`. I figured it had something to do with the cross-validation part as it works for `glmnet` alone. Thank you. Appreciate your time.

Comment: No worries, I apologize for not properly reading your question in my first glanceover. :-)

Comment: Could it be nulldev - nulldev * dev.ratio, instead of nulldev - nulldev * (1 - dev.ratio)?

Comment: nulldev - nulldev ( 1 - dev.ratio) = nulldev(1 - (1 - dev ratio)) = dev.ratio * nulldev, so no, not in this case.